# How to fix the error while calling stripe payout create API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am calling the Stripe Payout create API from Ruby on rails, but I am getting error from Stripe. My aim is to credit a particular amount to the client credit card.

The code is:

```
transferForRenter = Stripe::Payout.create(:amount => 100, :currency => "usd", :destination => payment_customer_id)
```

The response I got from Stripe is:

---

{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such external account: cus_XXXyoOyVJRUXXX",
    "param": "destination",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }

### }

Comment: Need to passed source token

Comment: I am calling the Stripe API from a ruby task. Is it possible to get the customer token using code?

Comment: You're trying to create a Payout to a customer?  I don't think Stripe supports that. The destination is supposed to be your bank account or card.

Comment: `cus_XXXyoOyVJRUXXX` is a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers) ID. The [destination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create#create_payout-destination) of a payout can't be a Customer, it's an [external account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_accounts)(a saved card or bank account on a Connected account : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts )

Comment: I was able to transfer payment to the customer bank account with the Transfer API. But, my requirement is to sent payment to a customer linked card. Is that possible in Stripe?

Comment: You have to use transfer, not payout.  You can create a custom account for the customer and add external accounts to represent the payment / transfer option and then specify the external account representing the customer linked card.  I'm not sure of the exact mechanics as I haven't done it, but if you research that approach the stripe documentation should help you achieve it.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible what you are doing but from my understanding you need to create a connect account with an external account for any user to receive a payout.  I'm not entirely sure how you would send a payment with only a credit card number without it being some refund of some sorts - although i could be wrong and again, its possible and should be possible.  You can always hit up stripe if no1 helps